# Get child of node by class (HTML template)

Tags: javascript, html, nodes

I have a template that I will be adding to the body multiple times. Each one will be the same, except the text in one of the elements will be different:

```
<template id="template">
  <div class="activity">
    <p class="activityName"> <!-- to be changed -->
    </p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
      Edit
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
```

When I insert this template, I wants to edit the `.activityName` element. I could use `Node.firstChild`, but that means that if I change the HTML in the future, this setup might break if that element is no longer the first child. Is it possible to retrieve it by class from that specific node? Something like this:

```
var template = document.getElementById("template");
var clon = template.content.cloneNode(true);
clon.getElementsByClassName("activityName")[0].innerHTML = "text"; //this line needs changing
document.body.append(clon);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about using:

```
clon.querySelector(".activityName").innerHTML = "text";
```

The `querySelector` function finds the first element that matches with the specified selector, in this case, our selector is `.activityName` this means that the function will find the first element with the class `activityName`

Now, if you want to get all the nodes with the same class, you have to use the `querySelectorAll` function

I see that you used `template.content` but there is not a property called `content` in template element, maybe you mean something like `var clon = template.querySelector('.activity')`

Comment: I read in a tutorial before that template.content is one way of doing the desired task. I checked, and it works, so there is no problem there. Your solution works - exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!